# How to (remove/make invisible/change color) border for input field in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, input-field, unity3d-gui

How I can `remove border for input field`? Or can i make it invisible, change color? I have not found the answer to this question in Google. I tried to change the border color in the Inspector, but it did not. Help me, please.

Comment: The default input field of Unity uses an image as [`TargetGraphic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/UI_InputFieldInspector.png), just change the sprite used by this image

Comment: @Hellium Thank you, dude:)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Hellium for your answer in the comments. I put it in answer for anyone who need it.

"The default input field of Unity uses an image as [TargetGraphic](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/UI_InputFieldInspector.png), just change the sprite used by this image"